# How to escape "&#8217;" "&#8220;" when I used gzip.open() in python

Tags: python

I am totally new to Python, and when I use `gzip.open()` to deal with a .gz file, I get some codes like `"It&#8217;s one of those great ensemble casts that&#8217;s incredibly balanced"`.

How can I deal with it? The code I use:

```
def _review_reader(file_path):
    gz = gzip.open(file_path)
    for l in gz:
        yield eval(l)
```

the file is compressed from a json file

like:

```
{"reviewerID": "A11N155CW1UV02", "asin": "B000H00VBQ", "reviewerName": "AdrianaM", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "I had big expectations because I love English TV, in particular Investigative and detective stuff but this guy is really boring. It didn\'t appeal to me at all.", "overall": 2.0, "summary": "A little bit boring for me", "unixReviewTime": 1399075200, "reviewTime": "05 3, 2014"}\n
{"reviewerID": "A3BC8O2KCL29V2", "asin": "B000H00VBQ", "reviewerName": "Carol T", "helpful": [0, 0], "reviewText": "I highly recommend this series. It is a must for anyone who is yearning to watch \\"grown up\\" television. Complex characters and plots to keep one totally involved. Thank you Amazin Prime.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Excellent Grown Up TV", "unixReviewTime": 1346630400, "reviewTime": "09 3, 2012"}\n
....
```

and I want to get the review text but there are some code like `&#8217;`

Comment: What's the `eval(l)` for? You should be very careful with ever using this function at all, and it's almost certainly wrong in this situation. Use `yield l`, or better yet, replace the entire `for` loop with `yield from gz`.

Comment: That being said, the file contains HTML. And to interpret that you need to use an HTML parser. Show more of the (unzipped!) input file and explain what your end result should be for the given example.

Comment: emmm.. I am trying to update the question..

Comment: You'd have the exact same result if you used `gunzip` to create an uncompressed version of your input file and then used `gz = open(gunzipped_file_path)`, so why is this a question about `gzip.open()`? Part of building a [mcve] is making it *minimal* -- finding the smallest set of circumstances needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your JSON file does not seem to contain anything like `&#8217;` or `&#8217;`. You and since it is JSON, use a JSON parser (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: @Tomalak thank you soooo much!! I have solved it

Comment: See my answer, there are a few other points to pay attention to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking at JSON data, use Python's JSON parser to load it. It will automatically deal with any embedded escaped characters, such as `\n` or `\"`.

When reading from a gzip file, it's important to realize that gzip gives you raw bytes. These bytes must be tuned into text explicitly by calling `.decode()`, and in order to do that properly, you need to know what text encoding was used for the JSON. UTF-8 is a pretty safe default assumption, but it could be something else, depending on what was picked when the .gz file was written.

After the JSON is parsed, you can access the properties by their name:

```
import json
import gzip

def _review_reader(file_path, encoding="utf8"):
    with gzip.open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        json_text = f.read().decode(encoding)
        return json.loads(json_text)

for review in _review_reader(file_path):
    print(review['reviewText'])
```

---

If `reviewText` happens to contain HTML code instead of plain text, another step - HTML parsing - might be necessary. The [`lxml` module](https://lxml.de/) can help:

```
from lxml import etree

# ...

for review in _review_reader(file_path):
    text = review['reviewText']
    tree = etree.fromstring("<html>" + text + "</html>")
    print(tree.text)
```